# golang intellij idea - странности новой версии

Tags: golang, intellij-idea

Поставил IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)

```
Build #IU-221.5787.30, built on May 31, 2022
go plugin 221.5787.20
```

на место старой версии 2019.3. Прошло штатно, без ошибок. GOROOT / GOPATH тот же.
Подхватило директорию с тестовыми примерами. Запускаю, например, test_033.go Там два цикла на 117 и 58 итераций. Так вот 1-вый раз он отрабатывает и как положено выводит в консоль данные. На скане видно окончание 2-го цикла. Ошибок нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При втором и последующих запусках, ошибок нет, но выводит криво, например, так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. прошло 27 итераций 1-го цикла. Финиш. Потом 8 итераций второго цикла.
Захожу в дебаг - отрабатывает нормально. После перезагрузки первый раз всегда - ок, с последующих - криво и по разному. Может кто подскажет как исправить.

Comment: обычный баг в обычной IDE. Ничего необычного. Пользуйтесь нормальными IDE.

Comment: @KoVadim, в поиске .. что достойно внимания ?

Comment: мне нравится nvim/vim, vscode. Да, нужно будет чуточку напильничком пройтись (установить пару плагинов и все будет ок). И самое главное - никаких java на машине и нелицензионных продуктов.